# Metrizability of One-Point (Alexandroff) Compactification

Tags: general-topology, compactification

> Let $X$ be locally compact metric space, and $X^*$ be its one-point compactification, with the extra point being $\{\infty\}$. Then, the following are equivalent -
>
> 1. $X$ is separable
> 2. $X = \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty K_n$, where $K_n$ is compact and $K_n \subseteq K_{n-1}^\circ \ \forall n$
> 3. $X^*$ is metrizable

I've been able to prove $3 \implies 1$, but have failed to prove $2\implies 3$ or $1\implies 2$.

For $1\implies 2$, I think we have to use separability to get a countably dense subset, and use local compactness to get a countable collection of compact subsets $L_n$. I tried to define $K_n = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n L_i$, but this choice did not work.

For $2\implies 3$, I'm pretty sure we have to use the following metrization theorem -

> $X$ is metrizable iff every $x\in X$ has a countable neighbourhood system $\{U_n^x\}$ such that -
>
> 1. $y\in U_n^x \implies U_n^y\subseteq U_{n-1}^x$
> 2. $y\not\in U_{n-1}^x \implies U_n^y\cap U_n^x = \varnothing$

The choice $U_n^\infty = \{\infty\}\cup K_n^c$, where $A^c$ is the complement of $A$, seems like the most obvious choice. But, I've not been able to get a solution.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$$(3)\implies(1)$ is even easier than that: $X^*$ is a compact metrizable space, so it’s separable.

For $(1)\implies(2)$, note that $X$ is a separable metric space, so $X$ is second countable. Show that it has a countable base $\mathscr{B}=\{B_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ of open sets with compact closures. Let $K_0=\cl B_0$. Cover $K_0\cup\cl B_1$ with members of $\mathscr{B}$, take a finite subcover, let $U_1$ be its union, and let $K_1=\cl U_1$. Continue in this vein.

For $(2)\implies(3)$ I would use the Urysohn metrization theorem.

Comment: Hi Brain! I'm wondering if you could explain the usage of Urysohns metrization theorem for $(2)\implies(3)$?

Comment: @D.Math: $X$ is locally compact, so $X^*$ is a compact Hausdorff space. $(2)$ implies that $X$ is Lindelöf, and since $X$ is a metric space, that means that it is second countable. The sets $X^*\setminus K_n$ are a countable nbhd base at the point at infinity in $X^*$, so $X^*$ is second countable, and the Urysohn metrization theorem applies.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Why $X^*/K_n$ is a local base for $\infty?$ is it possible there exists a countable set in $X$ intersection all $X_n$?

Comment: @xyz: Let $U$ be an open nbhd of $\infty$; then $C=X^*\setminus U$ is a compact set in $X$. $X=\bigcup_n\operatorname{int}K_n$, so $\{\operatorname{int}K_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is an open cover of $C$ and therefore has a finite subcover. Clearly $\operatorname{int}K_n\subseteq\operatorname{int}K_{n+1}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, so that finite subcover has a largest element, say $\operatorname{int}K_n$. Then $C\subseteq K_n$, so $\infty\in X^*\setminus K_n\subseteq X^*\setminus C=U$.